# jQuery Firefly effect not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to implement a firefly effect on my Wordpress site.

When my designer created a static HTML site (http://fictiontech.net/cirko/) everything works just fine and the fireflies look great.

The I converted the site design to Wordpress (http://greenpeaklabs.com/cirko/) and now the fireflies don't appear anymore.

When I look in the console, it tells me that my initiating code:

```js
<script>
  //firefly effect
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.firefly();
  });   
</script>
```

it tells me "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" even though it's the exact same initialization as on the static HTML site.

I've also found a Wordpress site where the firefly effect works just fine (yootheme.com/demo/wordpress/radiance)

I've hit my head against this wall for a number of hours now, trying to scour the interwebs for solutions as well as reviewing working code to try and back into the problem, but no luck.  Any idea where the error is coming from and how I can make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WordPress is running jQuery in no-conflict mode, the $ alias is not defined – you should change your function call to either:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.firefly();
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.firefly();
});
```

Comment: I updated this and now it's throwing a different error in the console.  Do I need to change every instance of $ to jQuery in the entire code?

Comment: No, inside firefly plugin code the alias $ is passed as parameter, so you do not need to change it there. The new problem is, it can not find the HTML-element to add the effect to. It is trying to find an element with selector *#sliders_container*, as this is the default value. You can either add a new HTML element with id *sliders_container* to your markup or change your method call e.g to *jQuery.firefly({on: 'body'});* or some other existing element on page.

Comment: (In the working static example the firefly plugin code is a bit different than on your WordPress page - there the default element selector is *#firefly* and indeed there is a div with id *firefly* on the page.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and your comments.  If you look at the code for the cave splash image at the top, it is wrapped in a #sliders_container div (that is the only piece of content that I changed from the original so it applies to the appropriate section in the site)

To your point, I also tested #layerslider-container and it worked.  Hurrah!

Comment: OK, new conundrum but maybe I should break this out as a separate question.  When I include this code in the global section for my Wordpress theme, it breaks any Gravity Forms that have conditional logic.  But when I drop it in on only the homepage, then it doesn't work any more.  Any thoughts for how I can make this code specific only to the homepage?

Comment: OK, last comment, I promise.  I managed to force the missing Gravity Form to display, even though its a touch annoying to have to do that manually.  Website live at www.CirkoTeleskoptico.com!